# Performance of sketch drastically decreases outside of the P5 Web Editor

Tags: javascript, performance, p5.js

I was trying to add a p5.js sketch to my website, so as first try, I grabbed a sketch from Daniel Shiffman's 3D terrain generation with Perlin Noise video ([link 1](https://thecodingtrain.com/challenges/11-3d-terrain-generation-with-perlin-noise), [link 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IKB1hWWedMk)) to my [Svelte](https://svelte.dev/) project, when I noticed that the sketch seemed to be running much slower than it was in the p5.js [web editor](https://editor.p5js.org/).

To test my suspicions, I timed the execution of the draw call with `performance.now()`. Results in the p5.js web editor yielded an average execution time of `~10`ms. In my svelte project, execution time took about `80ms`. To confirm whether this was just a one-off problem, I threw together [a codepen](https://codepen.io/kemmel-dev/pen/LYvzXqp?editors=1111), and saw the execution times remained poor compared to the [web editor](https://editor.p5js.org/codingtrain/sketches/OPYPc4ueq).

To clear any doubts that this was Svelte or Codepen related, I created a new directy, threw in a boilerplate `html` file and imported p5.min.js from the CDN, and finally linked the `sketch.js`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.9.2/p5.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="./sketch.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Then, I ran my project using (npm) `serve`, and observed that the execution times were still the same. It's not `frameRate` related, (that should only dictate how often the draw call is called, but I tried experimenting with setting different framerates anyway, and the time it took for the draw call to execute stayed consistent throughout).

[This](https://editor.p5js.org/codingtrain/sketches/OPYPc4ueq) is the sketch I was experimenting with. My suspicion (although it is kind of a stab in the dark) is that it has to do with the `WebGL` mode used in that sketch (`createCanvas(600, 600, WEBGL);`), and that the web editor version is hardware accelerated, but my local project version is not. That's kind of a weird idea though, as to my understanding hardware acceleration should be enbaled browser-wide?

If anyone could elaborate as to why there is such a massive discrepancy between performance, and how I can make the sketch on my website run as smooth as the web editor one, it'd be hugely appreciated.

The contents of the particular `sketch.js` I was testing, originally written by Daniel Shiffman:

```js
// Daniel Shiffman
// http://codingtra.in
// https://youtu.be/IKB1hWWedMk
// https://thecodingtrain.com/CodingChallenges/011-perlinnoiseterrain.html

// Edited by SacrificeProductions

var cols, rows;
var scl = 20;
var w = 1400;
var h = 1000;

var flying = 0;

var terrain = [];

function setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 600, WEBGL);
  cols = w / scl;
  rows = h / scl;

  for (var x = 0; x < cols; x++) {
    terrain[x] = [];
    for (var y = 0; y < rows; y++) {
      terrain[x][y] = 0; //specify a default value for now
    }
  }
}

function draw() {

  flying -= 0.1;
  var yoff = flying;
  for (var y = 0; y < rows; y++) {
    var xoff = 0;
    for (var x = 0; x < cols; x++) {
      terrain[x][y] = map(noise(xoff, yoff), 0, 1, -100, 100);
      xoff += 0.2;
    }
    yoff += 0.2;
  }


  background(0);
  translate(0, 50);
  rotateX(PI / 3);
  fill(200, 200, 200, 150);
  translate(-w / 2, -h / 2);
  for (var y = 0; y < rows - 1; y++) {
    beginShape(TRIANGLE_STRIP);
    for (var x = 0; x < cols; x++) {
      vertex(x * scl, y * scl, terrain[x][y]);
      vertex(x * scl, (y + 1) * scl, terrain[x][y + 1]);
    }
    endShape();
  }
}
```

Comment: The code was not originally written by me, which made me hesitant of adding it here. I've added the code of the `sketch.js` I was testing as you asked, which belongs to Daniel Shiffman from his [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IKB1hWWedMk) 'Coding Challenge 11: 3D Terrain Generation with Perlin Noise in Processing'.